# Bootstrap Modal dialog catches first button on enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to trigger a `OnClick` event inside a boostrap modal using the enter button. The problem is it catches every button before the one I'm pressing on `enter` press.

What I need to do is press the button with .modalClose class when the `.modal-footer is visible`.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    modalFooter = $(".modal-footer");
    btnClose = $(".modalClose");
    if (e.keyCode == 13) //enter
    {
        if (modalFooter.is(":visible")) {
            modalFooter.find(".modalClose").click();
        }
    }
});
```

How can I avoid the "enter" press on every other button before this one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop anything happening first if enter key pressed:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    modalFooter = $(".modal-footer");
    btnClose = modalFooter.find(".modalClose");
    if (e.which === 13) //enter
    {
        e.preventDefault(); /* <-- here we stop the event */
        if (modalFooter.is(":visible")) {
            btnClose.click();
        }
    }
});
```

Side note, `.keyCode` is deprecated I believe, use `e.which`

Comment: Thank you this worked, but I'm having trouble with actually getting the correct modal-footer and modalclose button, any ideas on how I can get the one that is currently open and none other?

Comment: Do you have multiple open, is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't have multiple open, but it targets all of them even if they're not.

Comment: Actually now it doesn't even work with the e.preventDefault() and the code is the same.

Comment: What does this mean? `The problem is it catches every button before the one I'm pressing on enter press.` What do you mean by every button? You mean in the DOM? On the modal, are there several?

Comment: There's a exit button that doesn't save the form to the database and there's the "Save" button that I want to click on the enter press. The problem is it catches the Exit without saving button and doesn't reach the actual save to database one.

Comment: That's not what your question says. You said press the close button? `What I need to do is press the button with .modalClose class` What does the save button do? Fire an ajax call? If so, then on ajax success, close the modal